# Slow animate() in safari 5.1.7, but fine in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I'm doing here is animating a div container from one side to the centre, and when the arrow is clicked again it will move out of screen again. The div also contains two images, the blurred version and normal, which switches during the movement to give the appearance of motion blur. Everything looks good in the latest Chrome and firefox browsers, however in safari it is fairly choppy.

I know javascript animation is a hit or miss endeavour, but I'm curious to know if there is any way to optimize what I have now. Moreover, would what I am trying to achieve be accomplished using css3 animation? I'm led to believe css3 uses the hardware gpu, therefore eliminating any major slowdowns.

```
var cupcakeArray = new Array(new Array("Cupcake_01_blur.png","Cupcake_01.png"));


function loadCupCake(ini,direction){
    /*Set directional variables*/
    var dir = direction;
    var start;
    var end;

    var stageWidth = $('div#cupcakeStage').width(); //gets the current stage width 
    var centrepos = (stageWidth/2) - (743/2);


    if(dir == "left"){
        start = stageWidth;
        end = 0-743;
    }else if(dir == "right"){
        start = 0-743;
        end = stageWidth;
    }


    /*Remove the current cupcake in the centre*/
                    $('div.current-cupcake').removeClass('current-cupcake').addClass('remove-cupcake');

    $("div.remove-cupcake").animate({"left": end+'px'},{duration:500,easing:"easeOutQuart",complete: function() {
      $(this).remove();
    }});
    $("div.remove-cupcake img#img_blur").animate({opacity:1},{duration:100,easing:"easeOutQuart"});
    $("div.remove-cupcake img#img_normal").animate({opacity:0},{duration:300,easing:"easeOutQuart"});




    //preload images
    var num_loaded = 0;

    var $fragment;
    var $innerfrag;
    var img=[];

    $fragment = $('<div class="preload-cupcake" style="position: relative; left:'+start+'px;"/>');

    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
        img[i] = new Image();

        img[i].onload = function(){
            num_loaded++;

            if(num_loaded == 1){
                $innerfrag = $('<img id="img_blur" src="'+this.src+'" alt=""/>');
                $fragment.append($innerfrag);
            }

            if(num_loaded == 2){
                $innerfrag = $('<img id="img_normal" src="'+this.src+'" alt=""/>');
                $fragment.append($innerfrag);

                $('div#cupcakeStage').append($fragment);

                $('div.preload-cupcake').removeClass('preload-cupcake').addClass('current-cupcake');

                $("div.current-cupcake").animate({"left": centrepos+"px"},{duration:400,easing:"easeOutQuart"});
                $("div.current-cupcake img#img_blur").animate({opacity:0},{duration:700,easing:"easeOutQuart"});
                $("div.current-cupcake img#img_normal").animate({opacity:1},{duration:700,easing:"easeOutQuart",complete: function() {

                }});


            }

        }

        img[i].src = cupcakeArray[ini][i];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would download the free jquery CSS3 animation plugin Transit.  it uses CSS3 for animations and has fallback to animate on browsers that don't support them.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

It also supports animation queuing and on complete functions.